# Django ORM usage in template

Tags: django, templates, object, orm, iteration

I have created and object which contains a few students. I am trying to use each student to pull his data from another model as I iterate through my origianl student object known as `student_list`. I didn't post the view I made because I know that the object works fine.

I have the following models:

```
class StudentDetail(Base):
    student = models.OneToOneField('Usr', limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'Student'})
    klass = models.ForeignKey('Klass', related_name='kara_pore')

class Usr(AbstractUser, Base):
    type_choices = (
        ('Student', 'Student'),
        ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                 choices=type_choices,
                                 default='Student')
class Score(Base):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Usr, limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'Student'}, related_name='scored')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Usr, limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'Teacher'}, related_name='marked')
    exam = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    exam_date = models.DateField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
    out_of = models.IntegerField()
```

The template file:

```
{% for student in student_list %}
<tr>
    <td> <a href=#>{{ student }}</a> </td>
    <td> {{ student.student.scored.score }} </td> <-- this line doesn't work.
    <td></td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

The `student_list` object works and I can easily iterate through it. I am using that object to filter out data from the Score class. I have never used Zip in my view before. And I don't know whether this is an ideal situation for using that. As far as I know, using the dots to jump through classes should work and get me the value I need. I must be doing something wrong here. The template renders, but the score is not displayed.

Note: Here is my view.

```
def View(request, pk):
    this_klass = Klass.objects.get(id=pk)
    student_list = this_klass.kara_pore.all()
    return render(request, "grades/view.html", {'this_klass': this_klass, 'student_list': student_list})
```

Comment: You *do* need to show your view. How are you sure it works fine? Your view is responsible for passing this data to your template

Comment: I have iterated through my `student_list` object alone and it works fine. I cannot display the second cell in my table. But still I will show my view if it helps. @rnevius

Comment: I have added the view. Maybe this will help @rnevius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem:

```
{% for student in student_list %}
{% for score in student.student.scored.all %}
<tr>
    <td> <a href=#>{{ student }}</a> </td>
    <td> {{ score.score }} </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```